# No sound in Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: audio, ubuntu-10.10

I'm not able to hear any sounds from my PC after installing Ubuntu 10.10. Videos and mp3 files are all playing but no sound comes out of my PC. I formatted my previous Ubuntu 9.04 and did a clean install of Ubuntu 10.10.

**Output of lshw -c sound:**

```
saran@saran-desktop:~$ sudo lshw -c sound  
PCI (sysfs)  

  *-multimedia              
       description: Multimedia audio controller  
       product: 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) AC'97 Audio Controller  
       vendor: Intel Corporation  
       physical id: 1f.5  
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.5  
       version: 02  
       width: 32 bits  
       clock: 33MHz  
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list  
       configuration: driver=Intel ICH latency=0  
       resources: irq:17 ioport:e000(size=256) ioport:e400(size=64) memory:e8181000-e81811ff memory:e8182000-e81820ff
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also experienced something similar in Xubuntu and realised that there are different places to change the volume and to mute / unmute the audio. I'm sure it's more or less the same in Ubuntu. So check:

- The volume control in the task bar. Also right click and open the detailed settings. Is the correct audio card selected as output ?
- Search for alternative mixer settings in the menu. Most likely under Multimedia
- Maybe try alsa-mixer from a console
- Check if there are any hardware swtiches. Very unlikely if it's a PC, on notebooks there are sometimes hardware switches that overwrite any OS settings

Answer (score 1):

Toshiba Satellite Pro A120 - had no sound in 10.10. Did an upgrade to testing release 11.04 (press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> then type update-manager -d). I now have sound. 11.04 is looking promising -- after all I'm only playing with it so am happy to go with an unstable testing release.